# Developer tool extension, attach an event to every function call

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When debugging legacy code that is thousand of lines long, I found myself having the issue of trying to know what's the program is doing in very specific parts, so I've been trying to write my own developer tool extension that does what I need specifically; basically I need something that give me access to this or similar (example):

```
chrome.developer.v8.onFunctionCall = function(context, fn, arguments){
   log(context.process);
   log(context.id);
   log(context.declaration.url);
   log(fn.name);
   log(arguments);
}
```

Basically I need something that can do it similarly, it doesn't have to be exactly that; I haven't found anything like it in chrome extensions developer documentation.

Comment: I think you'll have to manually add conditional breakpoints at each function declaration with similar console.log sequence as the condition.

Comment: Well the point of using a extension is avoiding doing that, specially thousands of times; I'd even be happy by injecting into the javascript via hijacking the web request, but seems that's not possible.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, in that case you can use chrome.debugger API to [set up the breakpoints](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Debugger/#method-setBreakpoint) automatically on each function.

Comment: I can't have breakpoints set in every function call, that would be unbearable; I just want to log what it is doing, it's a functional program that is tangled.

Comment: console.log won't break the functions because it returns `undefined` so the only result will be logging.

Comment: No it won't but the thing is that they "can't" be put manually, otherwise it's not a developer tool if I have to modify thousands of javascript files to add a console.log to everything.

Comment: Using the debugger API you don't modify anything. The only problem would be finding/filtering line numbers but if you're okay with a simple regexp then it's not a problem worth mentioning.

Comment: Can you show an example?